# First time trying to use a foreign key other than model_id in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

So I know usually, a `belongs_to` associates models together based on the `id` column, but in my case I want to associate it by the `token` column instead.

For example:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :test_results
end
```

and

```
#app/models/test_result.rb
class TestResult < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
end
```

The `User` model has a column named `token`, and so when I create a new entry in `TestResult` that has the same `token` as what appears in `User`, I want the `TestResult` to be associated to that `User`.

I tried this in the model form:

```
#app/models/test_result.rb
class TestResult < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "token"
end
```

but when I go create a new test result, I can see that ActiveRecord is still looking for the `id` field that matches, instead of `token`.

```
2.5.1 :001 > TestResult.create(token: "Hello")
   (6.2ms)  SET NAMES utf8,  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
   (0.2ms)  BEGIN
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE `users`.`id` = 0 LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
 => #<TestResult id: nil, token: "Hello", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

Here's what my migration files look like:

```
class TestResults < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :test_results do |t|
      t.string :token

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.belongs_to :company, foreign_key: true
      t.belongs_to :platform, foreign_key: true
      t.string :token

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I know I am using the `foreign_key` wrong, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is the best solution, but just adding the `primary_key` function to the `TestResult` model in my case worked.

```
#app/models/test_result.rb
class TestResult < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "token", primary_key: "token"
end
```

Comment: I think it is the best solution, according to the api documentation - https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to

Comment: you should add unique index for your `token` column in `users` and `test_results` tables because it is used to find user so it must be unique. Index also helps your search faster.